# Empirical Process and Azuma's Inequality

Tags: probability, analysis, inequality

Given independent random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and a family $\mathcal{F}$ of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$, let
$$Z(X_1,\dots,X_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\left[f(X_i)-\mathbb{E}f(X_i)\right]\right|$$
Show that for any $t\geq 0$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|Z-\mathbb{E}Z\right|\geq t\right)\leq 2e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Attempt:
Apparently I have to apply Azuma's inequality to $Z$. Given two random vectors $X=(X_1,\dots,X_k,\dots,X_n)$ and $X'=(X_1,\dots,X_k',\dots,X_n)$ which agree in all but the $k$-th coordinate, if
$$\left|Z(X)-Z(X')\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
then we are done.
For each $f\in \mathcal{F}$, define $F_f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,n]$ by
$$F_f(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$$
Then we have to show that
$$\left|\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left|F_f(X)-\mathbb{E}F_f(X)\right|-\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left|F_f(X')-\mathbb{E}F_f(X')\right|\right|\leq 1$$
However, although it's clear that the difference above is at most $n$, why cannot it exceed $1$? Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of the function $F_{f}$ you define should be $\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $\mathbb{R}$.

Let me use slightly different notations. Define $\varphi$ by
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(x_1, \cdots, x_n) := \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} | \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f(X_i)]|
\end{equation*}
so that $\varphi(X_1, \cdots, X_n) = \sqrt{n} Z(X_1, \cdots X_n)$. If two vectors $(x_1, \cdots, x_i, \cdots, x_n)$ and $(x_1, \cdots, x_i', \cdots, x_n)$ agree on all but the $i$th coordinate, 
\begin{equation*}
| \varphi(x_1, \cdots, x_i, \cdots, x_n) - \varphi(x_1, \cdots, x_i', \cdots, x_n) | \leq \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |f(x_i) - f(x_i')| \leq 1
\end{equation*}
Then you can apply McDiarmid's inequality to deduce the exponential bound

---

Added:

The first inequality is derived as follows:
\begin{align*}
&\phantom{==}| \varphi(x_1, \cdots, x_i, \cdots, x_n) - \varphi(x_1, \cdots, x_i', \cdots, x_n) | \\
&= \bigg| \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |(f(x_1) + \cdots + f(x_i) + \cdots f(x_n) - \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[f(X_j)] | - \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |(f(x_1) + \cdots + f(x_i') + \cdots f(x_n) - \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[f(X_j)] | \bigg| \\
&\leq \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg| \left\{ (f(x_1) + \cdots + \color{red}{f(x_i)} + \cdots f(x_n) - \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[f(X_j)]  \right\} - \left\{ (f(x_1) + \cdots + \color{red}{f(x_i')} + \cdots f(x_n) - \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[f(X_j)]  \right\} \Bigg| \\
&= \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |f(x_i) - f(x_i')|
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on how you obtained the first inequality?

Comment: @InTheSea I added more details.

Comment: Oh thanks! Now it's clear to me. The expected values don't change and what vary are their realizations.